# Paramether in procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have trouble using table type as parameter in stored procedure.

```
This is my table type:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ TableTypeMyValue] AS TABLE(
    [MyValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
GO
```

I need @MyValue to be passed from c#:

```
 @BCID nvarchar(20),
@MyValue TableTypeMyValue READONLY


AS  
BEGIN


SET NOCOUNT ON  

SELECT IIF (EXISTS (SELECT bcc.BCID, ocv.CAID, ocv.CAValue
FROM BCTWO AS ocv
INNER JOIN BCONE AS bcc ON bcc.MyValue = ocv.MyValue
WHERE ocv.MyValue = @MyValue  AND bcc.[Part of the key] = 1 AND bcc.BCID = @BCID), 1, NULL)

END
```

This is error that i got:

```
    `Must declare the table variable @MyValue`.
```

I think that I have some problem with table type parameter. I'm not using it correctly. Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat `@CharacteristicValue` *as* a table, not the same as a scalar variable. You should probably *join* to it and have `ocv.CharacteristicValue = @CharacteristicValue` instead be an `ON` condition that references the `CharacteristicValue` column *within* the table.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a table type parameter like a scalar parameter, specially:

```
ocv.CharacteristicValue = @CharacteristicValue
```

You need to either use a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS` clause. For example:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM @CharacteristicValue CV
              WHERE CV.CharacteristicValue = ocv.CharacteristicValue)
```

Comment: Sorry I had to change the names !  OK I will try that!